# namespace error 'Not a namespace-name'

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm recently visiting namespaces as I have a group of functions/methods but no data, so the logical way to go would be to stick them inside a namespace. (Sorry if this question lacks anything).

I have the following:

Math.h

```
namespace Math {

   double Euclidean();

}
```

Math.cpp

```
#include "Math.h"
double Math::Euclidean() {
  // Implementation
}
```

And in another namespace, that I need to access the "Math" namespace:

```
namespace foo {

     foo();
}
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Math.h"
#include "foo.h"

using namespace Math; 

foo::foo() {
  // use the math function
  Math::Euclidean();
```

}

I get the error:

`Math’ is not a namespace-name`

I'm probably missing something really simple, but, I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have tried to read the following: [Here](http://nepsweb.co.uk/pgtcpp/namespace.htm) but it seems that this uses a class and I wanted to do it without using classes.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? The `double Math::Euclidiean()`, the `using namespace Math;` or somewhere else?

Comment: `"math.h"` is also a C standard header. Perhaps that's what the compiler is including.

Comment: Did you forget to paste some includes from the headers?

Comment: @BoPersson Even if I change the namespace to say `some` and change everything to this, I still get the error: `‘some’ is not a namespace-name`

Comment: @Phorce - What about changing the name of the include file? `"Phorce_Math.h"`, for example, isn't already taken.

Comment: Can you post a small code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Why are you `using namespace Math;` *and* fully qualifying the function name with `Math::Euclidean();`?

Comment: Does it error still if you change double Math::Euclidian to namespace Math { double Eucildian } ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has gotten stale for an hour, so I'm promoting @Bo Persson's intuitive comment.

> "math.h" is also a C standard header. Perhaps that's what the compiler is including.

You are likely using Windows, where `Math.h` and `math.h` describe the same file.

Rename your file so it doesn't have the same name as a standard library header and the compiler will see it.

Comment: I'm not using windows, no. But, I've just got home so I will do what you suggested, thank you.